# Create a flash file with c#

Tags: .net, flash

Is it possible to create a flash file programmatically using C# or VB.net?

I have a bunch of handwritten characters in coordinate form and I want to create a flash file that displays the characters one after the other. It must also play sounds while this is happening.

The ultimate goal is the convert a pencast as generated by a Livescribe smartpen to a flash file. This pencast file contains the characters as well as the audio.

Comment: Why the down votes? I think it's a perfectly fair question.

Comment: I cannot find Livescribe SDK anywhere. Does anybody have it? I can pay for it if needed. vova@77xy.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: You can use just about any programming language to create ActionScript files, and use the flex compiler to compile them. After all, code is only text - anything you can do in a manually written program, you can do in a generated one.